# Installing Definition Updates for Microsoft Security Essentials via VBS Windows Update

Tags: vbscript

I am attemptinng to install only the definitions updates for Security Essentials via VB script and I am running into a bit of bother.

I have gone through the MS provided scripts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), one of which downloads and installs all of the windows updates which is to and to risky, and I have also tried the specific updates script which does not seam to play ball when providing the full name of the definition I wish to download and install.

This is the MS code...  what I was hoping to do was pop in the script some where 'Definition Update' and run this on a daily basis to check for regular updates

Any clue's would be very welcome
Regards
C

```
`Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
updateSession.ClientApplicationID = "MSDN Sample Script"

'Get update title to search for
WScript.Echo "Enter the title of the update: " & _
"(for example, Update for Windows Rights Management client 1.0)"
updateTitle = WScript.StdIn.Readline

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Searching for: " & updateTitle & "..."

Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

'Search for all software updates, already installed and not installed
Set searchResult = _
updateSearcher.Search("Type='Software'")

Set updateToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

updateIsApplicable = False

'Cycle through search results to look for the update title
For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
   Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
   If UCase(update.Title) = UCase(updateTitle) Then
   'Update in list of applicable updates 
   'Determine if it is already installed or not
      If update.IsInstalled = False Then
         WScript.Echo vbCRLF & _
         "Result: Update applicable, not installed."
         updateIsApplicable = True
         updateToInstall.Add(update)
      Else 
         'Update is installed so notify user and quit
         WScript.Echo vbCRLF & _
         "Result: Update applicable, already installed."
         updateIsApplicable = True
         WScript.Quit 
      End If
   End If 
Next

If updateIsApplicable = False Then
   WScript.Echo "Result: Update is not applicable to this machine."
   WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Would you like to install now? (Y/N)"
stdInput = WScript.StdIn.Readline

If (strInput = "N" or strInput = "n") Then 
   WScript.Quit
ElseIf  (stdInput = "Y" OR stdInput = "y") Then
   'Download update
   Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
   downloader.Updates = updateToInstall
   WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Downloading..."
   Set downloadResult = downloader.Download()
   WScript.Echo "Download Result: " & downloadResult.ResultCode

   'Install Update
   Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
   WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Installing..."
   installer.Updates = updateToInstall
   Set installationResult = installer.Install()

   'Output the result of the installation
   WScript.Echo "Installation Result: " & _
   installationResult.ResultCode
   WScript.Echo "Reboot Required: " & _
   installationResult.RebootRequired 
End If
`
```

Answer (score 1):

What a coincidence. I just made a solution based on direct links to definition updates found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971606. The downloaded file is about 90 MB but is only downloaded if new definitions are posted within a preset interval. Just save everything to a script file and make a task to run the script according to the interval you choose. Tested on XP and win7.

```
Option Explicit

DefinitionUpdate 24 'for checking every 24 hours

Sub DefinitionUpdate(interval)
    'Updates definition files for Microsoft Security Essentials
    Dim aUrl, sFile, dMod, dTime
    If OSBits = 32 Then
        aUrl = UrlTarget("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87342")
    Else
        aUrl = UrlTarget("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87341")
    End If
    dMod = Replace(Split(Filter(aUrl, "Last-Modified")(0), ",")(1), "GMT", "")
    'exit if no update in interval
    If DateDiff("h", dMod, UTCDate(Now)) > interval Then Exit Sub
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'save to temporary folder
        sFile = .GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & Mid(aUrl(0), InStrRev(aUrl(0), "/") + 1)
        If .FileExists(sFile) Then .DeleteFile sFile, True
        HttpSave aUrl(0), sFile
        'wait max 3 min for file
        dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 3, 0)
        Do While Not .FileExists(sFile) And Now < dTime
            WScript.Sleep 1000
        Loop
        If .FileExists(sFile) Then
            With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                .Run sFile, 1, True
            End With
            .DeleteFile sFile, True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function UrlTarget(sUrl)
    'Returns array with url after redirections together with all responsheaders
    UrlTarget = sUrl
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        Do
            .Option(6) = False  'no auto redirect
            .SetTimeouts 5000,5000,30000,5000
            On Error Resume Next
            .Open "HEAD", UrlTarget, False
            .Send
            If .Status = 301 Or .Status = 302 Then  'permanent / temporary redirection
                UrlTarget = .GetResponseHeader("Location")
            ElseIf .Status = 200 Then
                UrlTarget = Split(UrlTarget & vbNewLine & .GetAllResponseHeaders, vbNewLine)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Function

Sub HttpSave(sUrl, sFileName)
    'Save url to file
    Dim xHttp
    Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    xHttp.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    xHttp.send
    With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .type = 1 '//binary
        .Open
        .write xHttp.responseBody
        .savetofile sFileName, 2 '//overwrite
    End With
    Set xHttp = Nothing
End Sub

Function UTCDate(dateTime)
    'Returns UTC for dateTime
    With CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
        .SetVarDate(dateTime)
        UTCDate = .GetVarDate(False)
    End With
End Function

Function OSBits()
    'Returns 32 eller 64
    OSBits = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'").AddressWidth
End Function
```